# In the specific context of baseline traits of study participants (see ref.), what is p value? What's being tested and is it pointless? meaningful?

Tags: p-value, double-blind

(If answering, please assume readers already have a basic understanding of what *p* is in general.)

The *is it pointless* part of this question seems to be YES; that part of the question is similar to, and I'd guess answered by the answers to [Homogeneity testing of baseline characteristics in medical trials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58384/homogeneity-testing-of-baseline-characteristics-in-medical-trials) but I'm not sure, so I'd appreciate a confirmation.

Secondly and more importantly, perhaps, the *what is being tested* part of the question is asked there, but isn't answered, perhaps because, as @Gala notes, a specific reference is lacking there.  So that it can be answered, I now provide one (for my question), here: Table S1 at https://www.nejm.org/doi/suppl/10.1056/NEJMoa1205409/suppl_file/nejmoa1205409_appendix.pdf - from an article reporting on a double-blind medical trial.

Thirdly, and more specifically, when I ask, "meaningful?" it's because I'm wondering what the plain English meaning could possibly be of the p being just 0.01 in the chart for the subgroup trait/characteristic of diastolic BP but 0.67 for BMI  (when the meta characteristics seem similar - means are ~.35% apart, ± is ~6.6.)